# jQuery getting value of attribute inside while loop data coming from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, attributes

Let's set up the structure first.

message.php

```
<div class="msgcontent content" id="bodycontent">
  <div class="getmsglist"></div>
</div>
<script>    
  setInterval(function(){
    $('.getmsglist').load('processes/messagelist.php');
  }, 500);
</script>
```

messagelist.php

```
<?php while($mat = $stmt->fetch()){ ?>
  <div class="messagebox" this-chat="<?php echo $mat['mem_id']; ?>">
      // Other Stuffs
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

So above we can see that in `message.php` page the data gets loaded on `getmsglist` div from the `messagelist.php` page. On `messagelist.php` the attribute `this-chat` contains the user id. I want this user id to be fetched via AJAX. Currently, what I tried returned same user id for all rows. I need to fix that.

What I tried...!

```
$(".msgcontent").click(function() {
  var memid = $(".messagebox").attr("this-chat"); // doesn't work (fetches same id for all rows)
  //var memid = $(this).children(".messagebox").attr("this-chat"); // this returned undefined as well
  var dataString = {
    memid: memid
  };
  console.log(dataString);
});
```

The `$(".messagebox")` doesn't work here and it returns same user id for all rows. I tried "$(this)" instead but that returned `undefined` as it tries to fetch attribute of div ".msgcontent" which does not exist. How can I fetch this attribute value different for all rows?

Comment: `.msgcontent` is a wrapper div, which wraps your `.messagebox` items, what do you expect when click on it?

Comment: @u_mulder it opens up a modal and I want the id to fetch the relative content and display in the modal via ajax. I expect that when I click on it I get the respective value of each row from the `this-chat` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of requesting all `$('.messagebox')` you should be able to select a single `.messagebox` by delegating the click handler with [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('.msgcontent').on('click', '.messagebox', function() {
    var memid = $(this).attr('this-chat');
    var dataString = { memid: memid };

    console.log(dataString);
});
```

This way your click handler is bound to the container `.msgcontent` but delegated to `.messagebox`. This way the handler can be bound before there's actual content loaded.

---

Now I'm not entirely certain about the custom attribute `this-chat`. It's more logical to use `data-chat`.

```
var memid = $(this).data('chat');
```

The data attributes will be converted automatically if you need an integer instead of a string. But first try to actually get your object in the console log.